# Spring Data Jdbc: Name must not be empty error on nested one to many relationship implementation

Tags: java, spring-data-jdbc

I'm using `Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE` and `spring-data-jdbc 1.1.0.RELEASE`

Tried to implement nested one to many relationship using spring-data-jdbc.

One book has many chapters and each chapter has many parts.

```java
public class Book {

    private Set<Chapter> chapters = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Chapter> getChapters(){
        return chapters;
    }
}

public class Chapter{
    public Set<Part> getParts() {
        return parts;
    }

    private Set<Part> parts = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Part { }


public interface BookCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
    public Set<Book> findAll();
}


@Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepository;

@GetMapping("/book")
public Set<Book> getBookList() {
    return bookCrudRepository.findAll();
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chapter (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    book_id int references book(id),
 );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS part (
    chapter_id int references chapter(id),
);
```

Without Part, findAll returns all Books with Chapters. With Part, I received this runtime error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name must not be empty!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.domain.Identifier.withPart(Identifier.java:116) ~[spring-data-relational-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.resolveRelation(BasicJdbcConverter.java:349) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.readOrLoadProperty(BasicJdbcConverter.java:333) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.populateProperties(BasicJdbcConverter.java:322) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.createInstanceInternal(BasicJdbcConverter.java:458) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.mapRow(BasicJdbcConverter.java:307) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter.mapRow(BasicJdbcConverter.java:252) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.EntityRowMapper.mapRow(EntityRowMapper.java:68) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Comment: How does your method looks like when you call findAll with the parts?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I call bookCrudRepository.findAll() only

Comment: Is it intentional that "part" does not have a primary key? I'm sure that's why you're getting the `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source you posted none of your entities has an id, although the schema shows `Book` and `Chapter` probably have one.

`Page` needs one as well if it is supposed to be stored in a `Set`.

Basically the aggregate root (`Book`) and all entities stored in a `Set` need an id.

Entities referenced directly or via a `List` or a `Map` don't need an id since the get the id from the referencing entity plus the list index or map key.